# Is there a way to remove disclaimers/irrelevant information at the top of your data sheets?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I've been given some data to analyse and the first row of each sheet contains a disclaimer(or any other piece of information that is not pertinent to the dataset), such that when I read the file on Jupyter, the disclaimer is obtained as part of the header. The headers are actually in the second row of the sheet.

[A snapshot of the first and second rows of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffqHv.png)

Is there a way to screen such disclaimers out using python to the effect that only the actual headers are made manifest and the datasheet itself remains untampered with?

Comment: How are you reading the file? Could you provide the code you're having troubles with?

Comment: Are you asking how to delete the disclaimers from the files, or asking how to retrieve the data from the files without retrieving the headers?

Comment: Oliver, I'm asking how to retrieve the data from the files without the disclaimers.

Comment: PL, I used `pd.ExcelFile` to read the file and `pd.read_excel` to retrieve each sheet. I'm not having troubles with the code per se, I just want to retrieve the sheets without the disclaimers being a part of it.